# How to avoid auto increment of primary key in inserting query?

Tags: c#, sql-server

First I allowed user to type in combo box to search quickly when there are many projects. I was wondering if I can stop the insert query if the user accidentally press an additional letter and it will cause null, and I had `try catch` block but it only shows error message but the primary key skip a number.

Selecting ProjectID to fill comboBox

```
private void GetProjectID()
{
    newConnection.ConnectionM();
    SqlCommand cmd = SqlConnectionOLTP.cn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Project where ProjectName='" + comboBoxProjectTitle.Text + "' ";
    try
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            ProjectID = reader.GetInt32(0);

        }
        reader.Close();
        SqlConnectionOLTP.cn.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Inserting to database:

```
SqlCommand cmd = SqlConnectionOLTP.cn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into Cost(ProjectID,PropertyID,CostCategoryID,EstimatedAmount) values ('" + ProjectID + "','" + PropertyID + "','" + CostCatID + "'," + "'" + textBoxAmount.Text + "') ";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlConnectionOLTP.cn.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Saved");
```

Comment: seriously: never ever concatenate input to make SQL; that is "databases 101" - or at least "105" (and has been OWASP #1 ("A1") *forever*). Please please please use parameters.

Comment: "but the primary key skip a number" - that... isn't a problem; you should not *expect* that the primary keys are all contiguous, and IMO it is a very bad idea to try to "fix" this - that is solving the wrong problem; what is the *actual issue* here?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <TableName> ON
-- Do the inserting in the table with name <TableName>
SET IDENTITY_INSERT <TableName> OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

**Run this code on SSMS i.e sql server management studio**

```
 ALTER TABLE [Project] DROP ProjectID 
   SET IDENTITY_INSERT <Project> OFF
```